# Sencha Test. Test unavailable element

Tags: testing, extjs

I have an element with xtype: 'usersList'
I need to verify in test that this element is not present at the moment. How can I do this using Sencha Test (v. 2.0.0)? *ST.component('usersList')* will cause test failure...

Answer (score 2):

### INBROWSER SCENARIO

`ST.component()` expects, that component is present, so you can't use it in this way.
You can use this:

```
ST.play([{fn:function(){
  expect(Ext.first('userList')).toBeDefined();
}}]);
```

And FYI - if you need wait for element (animation or fill grid), you can use

```
ST.wait(function(){
  //waiting for UserList
  return Ext.first('userList');
});
```

### WEBDRIVER SCENARIO

This need different approach. Try this code -

```
describe("webDriver", function() {
    it("should return true if userList is not present", function() {
        ST.execute(function () {
            return Ext.first('userList') < 0;
        })
        .and(function (future) {
             expect(future.data.executeResult).toBe(true);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Documentation should help you too. For this example - [ST.execute()](http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/2.0.0/api/ST.html#method-execute)

Comment: I have tired 

`
    it("does not shows userslist view", function () {
        ST.play([{fn:function(){
            expect(Ext.first('userslist')).toBeDefined();
        }}]);
    });
`

but got an error
`
    Failed with error "javascript error: Cannot read property 'call' of   undefinedJavaScript stack:TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined    at Object.window.$ST.call (eval at executeAsyncScript (:438:5), ....."
`
By the way. I use Sencha Test 2.0.0 with WebDriver for local browser pool and ExtJS 6.0

Comment: I updated my answer - can you check, if it is resolve your problem?

Comment: I do not know why but Ext.first from ST.execute returns null value even if element should be present on the page.